# What is the best practice to use when including many similar CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have my css set up like so:

```
.options {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 14%;
    top: 0;
}

#opt1 {
    margin-top: 5.4%;
}

#opt2 {
    margin-top: 12.4%;
}

#opt3 {
    margin-top: 19.4%;
}

#opt4 {
    margin-top: 26.4%;
}

#opt5 {
    margin-top: 33.4%;
}
```

That's a lot of code when I'm really only changing one element in the CSS. Would it be better to do this in Javascript? Or is it better for performance for the CSS to run this? I want to adhere to best practices and I'm not sure if this is an acceptable way to write this or if I should change something. Thanks in advance, I'm pretty new to this.

Edit: Why the downvotes? Did I say something incredibly stupid?

Edit2: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your concern is here, and "how to best..." is largely opinion based anyway.

Comment: When styling, using CSS is the rule. :) Some explanation would be useful here, the answer may depend on what you're trying to achieve with the code. Try putting the HTML / CSS in a JSFiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net. When you give it a title you can share the link here for others to see

Comment: I guess you got downvotes because the question can't be answered clearly. The best practice depends a lot on your use case.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HTML markup that goes along with the CSS. That said, this question may be a better fit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Without the knowledge of the context of your project:
Your way is fine.

What I do in cases like that is to use only one line per item, makes the code a bit more readable:

```
#opt1 { margin-top:  5.4%; }
#opt2 { margin-top: 12.4%; }
...
```

I don't see any reason to use JavaScript for styling your items.

Inline styling was proposed in another answer, if that makes sense depends on your project: do you need the id's for other things (JS)? Do you want all CSS code in one file or could your project be more readable with inline CSS?

As a conclusion:
There is no way around having a few lines of code, because every element has another margin value. No matter the method, you have to write that code in one form or another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your concern with this code is, but assuming the `#optX { margin-top .. }` rules apply to only a single element ever on your page, just write it as one-off inline style on the element itself:

```
<div id="opt1" style="margin-top: 5.4%">
```

There's no reason to dogmatically put everything into an external CSS file when it's not even reusable.

Comment: Inline CSS? Really? Minify, Gzip etc will do just fine compressing rules as written in the OP. But regardless, this is an opinion-based question and not really within Stackoverflow's usage.

Comment: *No* inline CSS? Really? It simplifies the code greatly, and if anything has a *positive effect* on file size (you can probably get rid of an id or class and it makes the external CSS file smaller). – It's perfectly reasonable to use inline CSS where it's appropriate. Again, dogmatically going in either direction is of no use.

Comment: Depending on the application you're working on, it's easier to maintain one CSS file rather than various webpage

Comment: you could use a mixin, are you coding with a CSS preprocessor ?

Comment: @Jorel Depending on the application you're working on, it's easier to maintain inline styles rather than having to associate elements with rules in an external CSS file via made up classes or ids. **It goes either way.**

Comment: Oh ? Depending on what ? Either it's a small project, therefore a small CSS will be fine to maintain, either it's a big one, and it'll be easier to maintain 1 file. What kind of application make it easier to use inline CSS exactly ?

Comment: @Jorel *You* started with the "depending"... ;-P – Seriously though, if you have *one single unique element* which you need to apply *one one-off* style to... you know this style is not shared anywhere else, this element appears nowhere else... is it easier to just add a `style=".."` to it, or to 1) create a unique, sensible id or class, 2) find an appropriate place in the appropriate CSS file to 3) add the style there; knowing you will never use this id/class anywhere else for any other purpose...?

Comment: @deceze Yes it's easier, but not easier to maintain :) I was working as a front-end developper for a company a while ago, abd the guy before me used to do little inline CSS. The problem was that i had access to CSS files only on the serv, i couldnt modify the HTML because all the content was hosted on an external CDN which required credentials that i didnt had. My boss and i were in different timezone, so i had to wait for him to log in to have access to the files, modify them, send it back to him and then he would upload those on our CDN. The guy probably saved 10 sec, we lost 6 hours :)

Comment: @Jorel That's a pretty specific situation I wouldn't generally regard as valid reason against inline CSS...

Comment: @deceze and i guess there's ton of pretty specific situation where inline css caused more troubles that it saved times :) The way i see it is every CSS at the same place doesnt cost anything much and could potentially prevent unpleasant situation. Therefore it's purely opinion based, i don't see any major nor minor advantage using inline-css, but  only potential pretty specific problems

Comment: @Jorel Stuffing *everything* into one CSS file leads to ginormous CSS files, hundreds of class/id names which all need to be chosen sensibly so as to not clash, and IMO can create much more of a headache and maintainability issues. **Both strategies have their uses and their problems.** You need to decide based on your situation.